# Neo4j condition checking for going through relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a news update system like this

> ```
> user-[:post]->(upd1)
> user-[:post]->(upd2)
> user-[:next_post]->(upd2)-[:next_post]->(upd1)
> ```

if i need to query for current month updates i can retrieve updates 2ways

1. create a time property on node and query like this

> ```
> MATCH user-[r:next_post*1..]->(upd)
> WHERE r.time > sometime
> ```

1. create a time tree and make a relation between every upd and corresponding time node and do this

> ```
> MATCH user-[r:next_post*1..]->(upd)
> MATCH (upd)-[:in]-(exptime)
> ```

is any better way?
is there any way to stop traversing `[r:next_post*1..]` when a condition is false, i mean stop touching relations not filter them after inspecting their property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher is not yet fully optimized for this use-case (this will change soonish though).

I'd either go with the time tree as you suggested, or look into the example I provided here for an [Neo4j Server extension using the Java-API](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-activity-stream).